# Can Python's functional programming be used to completely avoid interpreter and method overhead?

Tags: python, performance, sqlite, functional-programming, python-itertools

I want to achieve near-C speeds for working with sqlite and regex pattern searching. I'm aware of other libraries and FTS4 that will be faster or alternative solutions, but that's not what I'm asking.

I've discovered that as long as I don't use lambda or defined methods, or python code at all, certain primitives and C level functions exposed by CPython can be injected directly as sqlite custom functions, and when run, a boost of 10x is achieved, even if there are no operations done except return a constant. However, I'm not ready to dive into creating extensions, and I am trying to avoid having to use a tool like Cython to intermix C and python together.

I've devised the following test code that exposes these performance differences, and makes use of some speedups provided by a third party library, cytoolz (compose method) to achieve some functional-style logic while avoiding lambdas.

```
import sqlite3
import operator
from cytoolz import functoolz
from functools import partial
from itertools import ifilter,chain
import datetime
from timeit import repeat
import re,os
from contextlib import closing
db_path='testdb.sqlite'
existed=os.path.exists(db_path)
re_pat=re.compile(r'l[0-3]+')
re_pat_match=re.compile(r'val[0-3]+')
with closing(sqlite3.connect(db_path)) as co, co as co:
    if not existed:
        print "creating test data"
        co.execute('create table test_table (testval TEXT)')
        co.executemany('insert into test_table values (?)',(('val%s'%v,) for v in xrange(100000)))

    def count(after_from=''):
        print co.execute('select count(*) from test_table %s'%(after_from,)).fetchone()[0]

    def python_return_true(v):
        return True

    co.create_function('python_return_true',1,python_return_true)
    co.create_function('python_lambda_true',1,lambda x: True)
    co.create_function('custom_lower',1,operator.methodcaller('lower'))
    co.create_function('custom_composed_match',1,functoolz.compose(partial(operator.is_not,None),re_pat_match.match))
    data=[None,type('o',(),{"group":partial(operator.truth,0)})] # create a working list with a fallback object
    co.create_function('custom_composed_search_text',1,functoolz.compose(
        operator.methodcaller('group'), # call group() on the final element (read these comments in reverse!)
        next, # convert back to single element. list will either be length 1 or 2
        partial(ifilter,None), # filter out failed search (is there a way to emulate a conditional method call via some other method??)
        partial(chain,data), # iterate list (will raise exception if it reaches result of setitem which is None, but it never will)
        partial(data.__setitem__,0), # set search result to list
        re_pat.search # first do the search
    ))
    co.create_function('custom_composed_search_bool',1,functoolz.compose(partial(operator.is_not,None),re_pat.search))
    _search=re_pat.search # prevent an extra lookup in lambda
    co.create_function('python_lambda_search_bool',1,lambda _in:1 if _search(_in) else None)
    co.create_function('custom_composed_subn_alternative',1,functoolz.compose(operator.itemgetter(1),partial(re_pat.subn,'',count=1)))
    for to_call,what in (
            (partial(count,after_from='where 1'),'pure select'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where testval'),'select with simple compare'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where python_return_true(testval)'),'select with python def func'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where python_lambda_true(testval)'),'select with python lambda'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where custom_lower(testval)'),'select with python lower'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where custom_composed_match(testval)'),'select with python regex matches'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where custom_composed_search_text(testval)'),'select with python regex search return text (chain)'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where custom_composed_search_bool(testval)'),'select with python regex search bool (chain)'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where python_lambda_search_bool(testval)'),'select with python regex search bool (lambda function)'),
            (partial(count,after_from='where custom_composed_subn_alternative(testval)'),'select with python regex search (subn)'),
    ):
        print '%s:%s'%(what,datetime.timedelta(0,min(repeat(to_call,number=1))))
```

output with Python 2.7.8 32-bit (OS: windows 8.1 64 bit home), print statements omitted:

```
pure select:0:00:00.003457
select with simple compare:0:00:00.010253
select with python def func:0:00:00.530252
select with python lambda:0:00:00.530153
select with python lower:0:00:00.051039
select with python regex matches:0:00:00.066959
select with python regex search return text (chain):0:00:00.134115
select with python regex search bool (chain):0:00:00.067687
select with python regex search bool (lambda function):0:00:00.576427
select with python regex search (subn):0:00:00.136042
```

I'm probably going to go with some variation of the "select with python regex search bool (chain)" above. So my question is 2 part.

1. Sqlite3 will fail if a create_function() call creates a function that returns anything but a primitive that it understands, so the MatchObject that search() returns needs to be converted, hence the chained "is not null" method. For the search-text-returning function, this turns ugly (not very straight forward) as you can see in the source. Is there an easier alternative than the element-to-iterator conversion strategy I used when trying to make a non-python function optionally show MatchObject's group only if it is returned after searching a regex for use with sqlite3?
2. I am continuously battling with the speed of Python: whether to use database functions over python functions, or lists instead of dicts or objects, wasting lines of code copying variable names to the local namespace, using generators instead of additional method calls, or inlining loops and functions instead of benefiting from abstractions that Python can provide. What are some other functions / libraries that I should consider that will allow me to achieve huge efficiency payoffs (I'm talking at least 10x) while still using Python for scaffolding? I'm aware of programs that actually speed up the python code itself (pypi, cython), but they seem more risky to use or still suffer from how python's language constructs restrict optimization because it is assumed that the code is always 'interpreted'? Perhaps there are a few ctypes exposed methods and strategies that could pay off in the realm of fast text processing? I am aware of the libraries focused on scientific, statistical and mathematical speedups but I'm not particularly interested in that realm.

Answer (score 0):

I recently did some tests and have looked at other ways to speed up text processing tasks. A major breakthrough, and something Python is well equipped to do, is meta-programming. I write code that combines and transforms code snippets that do specific operations on rows of a text file. The method overhead is eliminated because it's all one method, and another major benefit is auto re-mapping of attributes to either array index lookups, or when tradeoffs permit, automattic local mappings. The code snippets can be written in such a way that they can run and tested both as-is and as part of a combination of other snippets. Tracking where each snippet came from can be added as comments in the result of the compiled python source code.

This seems to be the easiest way to go while staying true to Python and getting all (or most) of the benefits the language can offer without worrying (as much) about the performance pitfalls of an always-interpreted language.

Thanks to all 54 viewers for your contributions. ;)